# I need to make a Startup Disk

Tags: startup, testdisk

I am using XUBUNTU 15 10. I want to make a Startup Disk that would help me log in if some problem arises. I tried to use the two available for Free download: (1) Startup Disk Creator (usb-creator-kde); (2) Startup Disk Creator (usb-creator-gtk). Both do not work for me. How do i make a working and performing Startup Disk for the XUBUNTU 15 10?

Thank you... Hariharan

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does it fail to make the disk or fail to boot from the disk? Please give any errors in full.

Comment: I am not able to make the boot disk nothing happens when I click "make startup disk"

Comment: Run it in a terminal like this `usb-creator-gtk` and see if there are any errors in the terminal when you try to make it and we can try to fix this, or you can try one of the answers below.

Comment: this brings the startup disk software instantly.. But that very thing doe not "move' or does not make any move... Nothing happens

Comment: It should start the application and In the terminal you started it from should be some output explaining why it is not working, some errors or warnings or something.

Comment: I get an error like tthis when i try to first Erase the CD: "org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.GLib.Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval =      etc etc

Comment: "Erase the CD" do you mean usb ? or DVD? Ubuntu won't fit on a CD

Answer (score 1):

The startup disk has a bug confirmed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746) when making a bootable USB for Ubuntu 15.10.

There is a workaround for this bug.

In Terminal:

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=16M ; sync
```

replace "X" with your usb key letter.

Comment: Don't forget to mention to change the ISO path too, OP has Xubuntu and may also have it in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most easy and proven to work properly and reliably method :

Use the Disks tool (`gnome-disk-utility`) to create the installation media.

Install the GNOME Disks tool - open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Select Restore Disk Image from the menu on the top right of the application.

Choose the installation ISO file and the USB drive to write it to - start restoring.

Comment: Just FYI `gnome-disk-utility` is not installed in Xubuntu 15.10 by default, but it is in the repos `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: @markkirby : Thank you very much for your information ! - I updated the answer with these instructions ... Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the kde version, but if you use `usb-creator-gtk`, make sure to have your USB stick formatted with fat32 before you start. Better even restart your machine after formatting it with fat32 (you can use GParted for this) so everything is informed that there only is a single fat32 partition on your stick.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a cd image of [XUBUNTU 15.10](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/wily/release/) at your hand.

Second, prepare an USB drive that have at least 2GB, backup its content if needed.

Last, right click the xubuntu cd image and choose `Open with Disk Image writer`. Choose your usb drive and click `Start Restoring...`

Comment: My need is STARTUP DISK

Comment: @HariharanPv, with that USB drive, you will be able to run a live season and do all kind of rescuing your computer and is also the same purpose of `Startup Disk Creator`. If I'm wrong, could you please define your STARTUP DISK ?